# Keeping Rails variables up-to-date for client-side use

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails template which uses a `javascript_tag` to get the variables `@user.lat` and `@user.lng` to the client for use in a function that generates a Google map.

The problem is that these variables are dynamic and can change often, but my javascript tag only knows the value of the variables at the time of page rendering. When I click around my app (triggering actual page loads) I can see that the values change, but the values in the `javascript_tag` aren't updated after the initial page load.

How can I keep the variables up-to-date on the client *without* refreshing the page or writing code to repeatedly query the server for these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'The javascript_tag approach you're taking doesn't support "watching" the variables for changes....'

Yes, true, even when I was clicking around my application and reloading the page, the values in the javascript_tag stayed the same. It was like once my js file loaded on start up of my application, the latitude and longitude values of @user stayed the same, even though they're supposed to change, and the map was always drawn with the same coordinates.

The 'Gon' gem didn't work for me either.  Very little documentation, especially for a novice like me.

What succeeded:

On the page where I wanted the map to be generated, show.html.erb:

```
<!-- This is here, to generate the user's latitude and longitude dynamically -->
<!-- The data-lat and lng attributes are used in 'initialise_google_maps' function, in scripts.js' -->
<div id="user-position" class="hidden" data-lat="<%= @user.lat %>" data-lng="<%= @user.lng %>"></div>
```

And then in my scripts.js:

```
function initialize_google_maps() {

    var user_longitude = $("#user-position").attr("data-lng");
    var user_latitude = $("#user-position").attr("data-lat");

var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);

var zoom = 10;
var myOptions = {
  zoom: zoom,
  center: currentlatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
    streetViewControl: false
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: currentlatlng, icon:{oppacity:0}});

  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    radius: 10000,
  });
  circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
}
```

Works a treat now.

Answer (score 2):

The `javascript_tag` approach you're taking doesn't support "watching" the variables for changes. In other words, your method of getting the data to the client is sort of "set it and forget it" and the client will never know if the value changes on the server without a page reload.

Another approach would be to use a pre-rolled solution for making dynamic server-side data onto the client, keeping an eye on them for changes, such as [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). Specifically, you might want to take a look at [the "watch" functionality](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch) provided by that gem.

Yet another approach might be to write up a function that makes an AJAX call to the server to request the latest value every so often. But then you'd just be hand-rolling a solution that does exactly the same thing as the previous suggestion.

Comment: Cheers chris, I'll check out Gon. Question looks better too.